# Variable scope - php - Using variables from one function in another

Tags: php, function, oop, scope

I am having trouble using a variable generated in one function, as a variable in a second function.

## The Problem:

I get *Notice: Undefined variable: parameter* in the validate function, on the line:

```
$this->$methodName($item,$value,$parameter) OR $valid=false;
```

When the function call for **splitRulesAndParameters** is simply replaced with the code within the function, the problem goes away.

## The Scenario:

The following two functions are both within the Validator class, the first, **validate**, makes use of the second, **splitRulesAndParameters**

Here is the validate function:

```
public function validate($data, $rules)
{
    $valid= true;

    foreach($rules as $item=>$ruleSet)
    {
        $ruleSetArray=explode('|',$ruleSet);

        foreach($ruleSetArray as $rule)
        {
            $this->splitRulesAndParameters($rule);
            
            $methodName='validate'.ucfirst($rule);
            $value = isset($data[$item]) ? $data[$item] : NULL;
            
            if(method_exists($this, $methodName))
            {
                $this->$methodName($item,$value,$parameter) OR $valid=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

And here is the splitRulesAndParameters function

```
public function splitRulesAndParameters($rule)
{
    $position = strpos($rule, ':');
    if($position !==false)
    {
        $parameter = substr($rule,$position + 1);
        $rule = substr($rule,0,$position);
    }
    else
    {
        $parameter='';
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense: `$parameter` is never declared... PHP will create a new variable for you (and initialize it to `null`), but it'll (rightfully) issue a notice

Comment: Modify your `splitRulesAndParameters()` to return an array of `$rule` and `$parameter`, and use the values from that array in the call to `$this->$methodName($item,$value,$parameter)`.... or use object properties for `$this->rule` and `$this->parameter`.... or even refactor to use a dedicated `Rule` class

Comment: Please see this recent post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842231/pass-php-var-from-one-function-to-another/25842271#25842271 and my comment on the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as the problem goes away if you *"inline"* the code in `splitRulesAndParameters`, I suspect the `$parameters` variable is used in that method. If so, simply have that method *return* the value of this variable, and assign it to a variable local to the `validate` method you've posted here:

```
$parameters = $this->splitRulesAndParameters($rule);
```

After adding this to the `splitRulsAndParameters` method:

```
return $parameters;
```

The method itself also modifies the `$rule` value. Again: this `$rule` variable is local to each method. It may have the same name, but the value is a copy. Any changes you make to `$rule` in `splitRulesAndParameters` is not reflected by `$rule` in your `validate` method. If I were you, I'd write:

```
public function splitRulesAndParameters($rule)
{
    $position = strpos($rule, ':');
    if($position !==false)
    {
        return array(
            'parameter' => substr($rule, $position+1),
            'rule'      => substr($rule, 0, $position)
        );
    }
    return array(
        'parameter' => null,//no param == null, IMO, change to '' if you want
        'rule'      => $rule
    );
}
```

Then, to change the variables in `validate`:

```
$split = $this->splitRulesAndParameters($rule);
$rule = $split['rule'];
$parameter = $split['parameter'];
```

That ought to do it.

*Side-note:*
You seem to be validating *everything* that needs validating, even if the first validation failed. If I were you, I'd change this fugly statement:

```
$this->$methodName($item,$value,$parameter) OR $valid=false;
```

To a more efficient:

```
if (!$this->{$methodName}($item, $value, $parameter))
    return false;//if validation fails, return false
```

That stops any further valiation from being executed: if one value is invalid, then just stop there. To continue is pointless, because the data-set is not entirely valid anyway.

*Bonus:*
Using a colon to separate the method name, and some parameter(s) does allow you to specify multiple params, too, and it allows you to simplify the `splitRulesAndParameters` some more:

```
protected function splitRulesAndParameters($rule)
{
    $all = explode(':', $rule);
    return array(
        'rule'   => array_shift($all),//removes first element in array
        'params' => $all//rest of the array
    );
}
```

Tweak this a little to better suite your needs

Comment: thanks Elias. that's what I call above and beyond =) You're points on simplifications are much appreciated as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use a variable from inside a function in another function. You have to **return** the variable `$parameter`. Add a return statement to the end of `splitRulesAndParameters` and store the result in a variable inside `validate` (`$parameter = $this->spli...`).

Comment: You've missed the bit where `$rule` is altered, too: returning `$parameter` alone doesn't quite cut it here

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Oh, right. But the OP seems to have abandoned the question anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two problems here, because you change the &rule variable inside your function, but you are passing it by reference. So after the fucntion is done the $rule variable is the same as it was before.

The way to solve this in the manner you are doing it right now would be to change the function to:

```
public function splitRulesAndParameters(&$rule)
{
    $position = strpos($rule, ':');
    if($position !==false)
    {
        $parameter = substr($rule,$position + 1);
        $rule = substr($rule,0,$position);
    }
    else
    {
        $parameter='';
    }
    return $parameter;
```

}

and change the line

```
$this->splitRulesAndParameters($rule);
```

to
    $parameter = $this->splitRulesAndParameters($rule);